# How to derive the maximum of a function shifted to the right as compared to the original function?

Tags: functions

[image]

f(0) = $\sqrt{0+1}$ = 1

f(1) = $\sqrt{1+1}$ = $\sqrt{2}$

How do I calculate the max value of a function shifted by 1 algebraically instead of plugging in values manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not only shifted. You need to investigate the expression

$$f(t+1)-f(t) = \sqrt{(t+1)+1}-\sqrt{t+1} = \sqrt{t+2}-\sqrt{t+1}$$

Now, just use the standard trick $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}$ and note that the denominator is strictly increasing for $t\geq -1$:
$$\Rightarrow f(t+1)-f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t+2}+\sqrt{t+1}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{-1+2}+\sqrt{-1+1}} = 1$$